# Match text not surrounded by & and ;

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am currently using the following regular expression:

```
(?<!&)[^&;]*(?!;)
```

To match text like this:

```
match1&lt;match2&gt;
```

And extract:

1. `match1`
2. `match2`

However, this seems to match an extra five empty strings. See [Regex Storm.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%26%29%5B%5E%26%3B%5D*%28%3F!%3B%29&i=match1%26lt%3Bmatch2%26gt%3B)

How can I only match the two listed above?

---

Note the existing pattern (`(?<=^|;)[^&]+`) by @xanatos will only match matches 1 to 3 in the following string and not match4:

```
match1&lte;match2&lt;match;3&#43;match&4
```

Comment: Why not `Regex.Split` with `&[gl]t;`? Also, replacing `*` with `+` will solve your current issue.

Comment: Try changing the `*` with the `+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It was `*` to `+` that I needed to do, thanks. And because there could be anything inside the `&..;` not just the `<` and `>`.

Comment: But if you use `[^&;]*` you will never match `&` and `;`. Do you really want that? This does not look safe. See what your regex will do to  [`match1&lt;ma;tch2&gt;` input](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%26%29%5b%5e%26%3b%5d%2b%28%3f!%3b%29&i=match1%26lt%3bma%3btch2%26gt%3b). Can you access *capturing group* contents?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, didn't think of that case. The general case is to match anything not inside of `&` and `;`. Where that can't contain `&` and `;`

Comment: I would use [`(?s)&[^;&]*;|((?:(?!&[^;&]*;).)*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%26%5b%5e%3b%26%5d*%3b%7c%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%26%5b%5e%3b%26%5d*%3b%29.%29*%29&i=match1%26lt%3bma%3btch2%26gt%3b) and grab Group 1 contents. (The last `*` might be replaced with `+` to avoid empty matches).

Comment: What is the exact environment you are using the regex in? Do you have access to code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew C# and .NET, hence the tags and yes

Comment: Then again, why not use `Regex.Split(s, @"&[^&;]*;").Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))`? No need for lookarounds then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm doing a `regex.Replace` on the string, the second one by xanatos works well though, thanks for your help.

Comment: There is one case where it won't work, but hopefully you won't have them. Good luck.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh `&` mid string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `*` to a `+`:

```
(?<!&)[^&;]+(?!;)
```

[Test here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%26%29%5b%5e%26%3b%5d%2b%28%3f!%3b%29&i=match1%26lt%3bmatch2%26gt%3b)

More correct regex:

```
(?<=^|;)[^&]+
```

[Test here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%3b%29%5b%5e%26%5d%2b&i=match1%26lte%3bmatch2%26lt%3b)

The basic idea here is that a "good" substring starts at the beginning of the string (`^`) or right after the `;`, and ends when you encounter a `&` (`[^&]+`).

Third version... But here we are showing how if you have a problem, and you decide to use regexes, now you have two problems:

```
(?<=^|;)([^&]|&(?=[^&;]*(?:&|$)))+
```

[Test here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%3b%29%28%5b%5e%26%5d%7c%26%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%26%3b%5d*%28%3f%3a%26%7c%24%29%29%29%2b&i=match1%26lte%3bmatch2%26ad%26ce%26d%3ba%26lt%3b)

Comment: there is one problem with this, it only works with maximum length of 2 leters insige

Comment: @MaciejKozieja Yep... You are right... It *is* correct for the question for the examples given (and it is the same base regex used in the question)... It is a limitation of the "base" regex... It wasn't the right way to do it.

Comment: yes i know that is limitation of regex but im just saying fact

Comment: @MaciejKozieja Suggested another regex, totally different

Comment: This won't work for an `&` mid string: `match1&gt;match&2`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yes, the string must be "correct" (the `&` and the `;` must be matched). Unmatched `&;` will break everything. This is a common limitation of simple tokenizers.

Comment: @xanatos Then it's close to what I need, just not exactly

Comment: @TheLethalCoder If you want to handle unbalanced `&;` it becomes difficult... There is probably a solution, but like I love to say... You had a problem, you wanted to use regexes to solve it, now you have two problems.

Comment: @xanatos I believe I have done it with the regex in my answer, your 3rd version also seems to work

Comment: The third version is also better than mine, as far as I can tell, because you don't have to go into the inner group to find out the text

Comment: Sorry i got notification and just responded asuming it was answer to prev question witch was removed so sory

Answer (score 2):

I have managed it with:

```
(?<Text>.+?)(?:&[^&;]*?;|$)
```

This seems to match all of the corner cases but it might not work with a case I can't think of at the moment.

This won't work if the string starts with a `&...;` pattern or is only that.

[See Regex Storm.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CText%3E.%2B%3F%29%28%3F%3A%26%5B%5E%26%3B%5D*%3F%3B%7C%24%29&i=match1%26dontmatch1%3Bmatch2%26dontmatch2%3Bmatch%3B3%26nomatch%3Bmatch%264%26nomatchplease%3B)

Comment: Much easier than mine... The power of the lazy quantifiers :-)

Comment: @xanatos Simpler but you have to access the text via the group instead of the match directly